# Can I get Google Authenticator as a stand-alone hardware dongle?

Tags: security, authentication, two-factor-authentication, google-authenticator

I'm setting up *Two-Factor Authentication* for our small office that will be used to log in to the corporate web site. The TFA is used via the [Google Authenticator](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1066447?hl=en) app that works great, except for a situation when a person doesn't own a smartphone.

So I was curious, can we buy a stand-alone hardware device (i.e. dongle) that could work as a Google Authenticator app?

Comment: It's usually called "2FA"

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Protectimus Slim mini](https://www.protectimus.com/slim-mini/) hardware tokens. These are programmable NFC TOTP tokens offered by Protectimus Solutions LLP - the company where I work. You can add the Google Authenticator seed in such token with the help of a special app and an Android smartphone supporting NFC, and it will replace the app.

Answer (score 1):

Three potential possibilities:

1. Are you securing Google Apps or Gmail?, if so you can phone authentication only as [per support](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6051686?hl=en).
2. In addition to Google Authenticator you can opt for hardware key based authentication like [YubiKey](https://www.yubico.com/why-yubico/for-individuals/).
3. Switch out Google Authenticator for alternative that will support phone call, SMS and app based authentication like [DuoSecurity](https://www.duosecurity.com/).

Comment: Sorry, have to downvote because of your suggestion number 3. Phone call or SMS/text is a **terribly insecure way** of TFA. [DO NOT USE IT](https://www.wired.com/2016/06/hey-stop-using-texts-two-factor-authentication/)!

Comment: Thanks @MikeF, however using the facts of today to down vote an answer provided more than 2 years ago is a bit unfair.

Comment: Secondly, the answer is still valid (ie DuoSecurity) as you get to choose which mechanism *you* want to use so er just disable phone and SMS